# finding out the metadata and joins

Tags: oracle, database-design

Suppose I have a database with a large number of tables.

- Is there any command that I can type in PL/SQL which display only the field names of a given table?
- Given any table is there any command that I can type that would show all the relations that it has with other tables?

For example , I have a table "TAB_1" , can I type a command that would show all the tables related to and for any table "TAB_2" that it is related to it would show which field in "TAB_1" corresponds to which field in "TAB_2 " .

Answer (score 1):

You can query the system views and look at metadata.

- [SYS.ALL_OBJECTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21644/systemtables.htm#CIACBHIF) gives you a list of all the objects that are accessible by the user
- [SYS.DBA_OBJECTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21644/systemtables.htm#CIAHIBAI) is similar and list all the object in the database
- [SYS.USER_OBJECTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21644/systemtables.htm#CIACCHCG) lists all the object owned by the user

You will get a list of tables using this view:

- [SYS.ALL_TABLES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21644/systemtables.htm#BABFEGHB) = tables accessible by the user
- [SYS.DBA_TABLES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21644/systemtables.htm#BABFHAEE) = all tables in the database
- [SYS.USER_TABLES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21644/systemtables.htm#BABICCDG) = tables owned by the user.

For a list of columns, you can join the TABLES list with the column views:

- Table Columns [SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm#I1020277), [SYS.DBA_TAB_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4146.htm#REFRN23277) and [SYS.USER_TAB_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4462.htm#REFRN26277)

There are similar views for:

- Constraints = [SYS.ALL_CONSTRAINTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn23047.htm#CHDFFJII), [SYS.DBA_CONSTRAINTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn23047.htm#CHDFFJII) and [SYS.USER_CONSTRAINTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn26047.htm#CHDGCFFB)
- Columns used by constraints = [SYS.ALL_CONS_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn23045.htm#I1023045), [SYS.DBA_CONS_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn23045.htm#I1023045) and [SYS.USER_CONS_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn26045.htm#CHDDCDAF)

You can then join some of them and write such a query for a list of columns involved in referential integrity contraints:

```
SELECT ...
FROM SYS.ALL_CONS_COLUMNS col
JOIN SYS.ALL_CONSTRAINTS con con ON col.owner = con.owner AND col.constraint_name = con.constraint_name
JOIN SYS.ALL_CONS_COLUMNS fk on fk.owner = con.owner and fk.r_constraint_name = con.constraint_name
WHERE con.constraint_type = 'R' AND col.table_name = '...'
```

With `R` being `(referential integrity)` for [constraint_type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm#i1576022).